# Invalid delegate for mailbox in Gmail API

Tags: java, gmail-api, google-api-java-client, google-email-settings-api

I am trying to get the Delegates for a mailbox using Gmail API.
My application is running on Google App-engine and has the feature of Add, Remove,Get Delegates using Email Setting API.
Now I am planning to migrate these features to Gmail API since Email setting API will be deprecated.

Technology wise I am using Java language.
I have followed all the steps provided by Gmail API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/get). Authentication to Gmail API is successful. But When I am trying to get the delegates it's giving following error-

> *404 Not Found
>   {
>     "code" : 404,
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Invalid delegate",
>       "reason" : "notFound"
>     } ],
>     "message" : "Invalid delegate"
>   }*

**And inside console below is the error -**

> *com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
>   {
>     "code" : 404,
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Invalid delegate",
>       "reason" : "notFound"
>     } ],
>     "message" : "Invalid delegate"
>   }
>
> at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.fro
>   m(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClie
>   ntRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClie
>   ntRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
>   $1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
>           at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1067)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
>   .executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
>   .executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>           at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
>   .execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>           ***at com.aeegle.services.GmailService.retrieveEmailDelegates(GmailService.
>   java:106)***
>           at com.aeegle.DAOImpl.EmailDAOImpl.getDelegatesGmail(EmailDAOImpl.java:1
>   43)
>           at controllers.DelegateController.getListDelegatesGmail(DelegateControll
>   er.java:82)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
>           at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
>           at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
>           at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
>           at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
>           at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:255)
>           at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:278)
>           at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:233)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
>   1)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
>   access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
>   run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)*

You can observe GmailService line number 106 have an issue. Now I am going to Post my java code.

1: - **Authentication Code -**

```
  public Gmail getGmailService(String email) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-------------getGmailService");

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        Collection<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
        SCOPES.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_BASIC);
        SCOPES.add(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
        SCOPES.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY);
        SCOPES.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY);
        GoogleCredential credential;
        // To load classpath resources.
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();  
        new File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL).setServiceAccountUser(email).setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH)).build();
        System.out.println("----calling Builder");
        service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

        return service;

    }
```

---

**2:- Next trying to get the Delegates for the mailbox using service object-**

```
public Delegate retrieveEmailDelegates(String user, Gmail service) throws Exception {
        if (isBlankOrNullString(user)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        Delegate delegatesResponse=null;
        try {

            System.out.println("Call retrieveEmailDelegates for "+user);
             delegatesResponse = service.users().settings().delegates().get(user, "me").execute();
            System.out.println("-------service" + delegatesResponse.getDelegateEmail());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return delegatesResponse;
    }
```

Please help me on this since I am still running this in my localhost machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access other users email account, you must turn on mail delagation that allows the delegate to read, send, and delete on their behalf:

1. ***Sign*** in to your [Google Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076).

   **Note:** *Sign in using your administrator account (does not end in 
   @gmail.com).*
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to **Apps**>**Gsuite**>**Gmail**> **User Setting**.
3. Next to **Mail delegation**, select **Let users delegate access to their mailbox to other users in the domain**.
4. (Optional) Select each organization containing users you want to enable mail delegation for and check the **Mail Delegation** box.
5. Click **Save**.

Once enabled, any user who wants to assign a delegate to access their email must [set up on mail delegation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en) in their Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work on Gmail and the Gmail API platform.*

Looks like you're trying to get a *list* of all delegates for an account, so you must use [`service.users().settings().delegates().list()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Settings.Delegates.List.html) instead of [`service.users().settings().delegates().get()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Settings.Delegates.Get.html).

Note that this will require further changes to your code, to deal with the returned [`ListDelegatesResponse`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/ListDelegatesResponse.html).

As an aside, you are receiving the `"Invalid delegate"` error because `service.users().settings().delegates().get(user, "me")` is supplying `me` as the email of the delegate you are attempting to retrieve. You'd need to supply a valid email address for the request to possibly succeed. However, I realize this is all likely due to your mistaken use of the `Get` delegate method instead of the `List` delegates method.